# How do I use variable in a query selector - js?

Tags: javascript, dom, let

What am I doing wrong?
there are 7 pictures with pre-made IDs from "img1" to "img7"

```
  function changeWidth() {
            let b = 50
            let k = 0
            let l = `"#img${(k + 1)}"`;
            for (let k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                
                document.querySelector("l").width = `${(b = b + 50)}`;

        }
```

Comment: don't surround it with quotes. and move the calculation into the loop

Comment: Also remove the quotes from inside your template literal.

Answer (score 0):

The comment covers the basics; move the template literal inside the loop, remove quotes from inside your template literal, and refer to the variable without quotes.

```
function changeWidth() {
  let b = 50
  for (let k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
    let l = `#img${(k + 1)}`;
    document.querySelector(l).width = `${(b = b + 50)}`;
  }
}
```

But you can actually simplify to not use any variables except the index in the loop, start `k` at `1` instead of `0` to avoid addition, and use `getElementById` which is more efficient than `querySelector`.

```
function changeWidth() {
  for (let k = 1; k <= 7; k++) {
    document.getElementById(`img${k}`).width = `${50 + 50 * k}`;
  }
}
```